# Devices connected to raspi router are not lan visible

Tags: networking, wifi, dhcp, hostapd

I have recently setup a RPi0W as a means to connect my Echo Dot to my University's WPA-Enterprise network (MSCHAPv2). I was successful in doing so following this [Wifi Repeater Guide](https://github.com/peebles/rpi3-wifi-station-ap) and modifying the wpa-supplicant file for PEAP authentication. However, while all connected devices are able to access the internet, they are not visible to each other on the local WLAN.

When I SSH into the router (RPi0W), all connected devices are visible by running `arp -a`.

`? (172.16.40.1) at 00:00:0c:9f:f2:00 [ether] on wlan0
? (172.16.40.194) at f0:d5:bf:b3:c1:e9 [ether] on wlan0
Main (10.3.141.73) at a4:5e:60:ef:1b:8b [ether] on uap0
amazon-cfab5703d (10.3.141.228) at 38:f7:3d:75:b0:39 [ether] on uap0
? (172.16.44.25) at d4:6a:6a:70:ae:db [ether] on wlan0
wemo (10.3.141.89) at 24:f5:a2:ff:0a:2d [ether] on uap0`

However when running that same command on a device connected to the AP (my Mac), it only shows the router. This doesn't allow me to setup WiFi IOT devices which need to be visible locally (my Wemo).

```
? (10.3.141.1) at b8:26:ec:ef:f3:d8 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It might not show up on arp, but you should still be able to ping/connect to devices on your network regardless - just note the IP from the router.

Answer (score 1):

This is all as expected so far. You are only looking at the arp cache where the kernel caches ip address to mac address mappings for a defined time, by default for 5 minutes when it has made a connection. This way it does not have to broadcast for the ip address with arp request every time it established a connection within the timeout. But if there was no connection the last 5 minutes then there is also no entry in the arp cache. The RasPi has connections to all associated stations so you see all its mac addresses in the arp cache. A client has only a connection to the RasPi and therefore you see only its mac address in the cache.

If the access point is setup the right way to a broadcast domain then you should be able to ping from a station (your Mac) a neighbor station (any other client connected). Then the kernel broadcasts by arp for the neighbors ip address and stores it in the arp cache. Look at it with `arp -a` afterwards.

If you cannot ping a neighbor then something is wrong with your setup.

Comment: If you can't ping a neighbour then the NAT routing to bridge the networks isn't set up correctly. https://github.com/peebles/rpi3-wifi-station-ap#bridge-ap-to-cient-side

Comment: @Dougie To ping a neighbor on the same subnet of the access point (**uap0**) there is no routing needed. You only have to ensure that the subnet is a broadcast domain what's default  normally. You only need routing if you want to go through the uplink router to the internet and you only need NAT if you cannot set static routes on the uplink router. The section you have linked to is named wrong with "*Bridge AP to cient side*". There is no bridge at all. There is routing enabled with `ip_forward=1`  between **uap0** and **wlan0**.

Comment: how do you know that ip_forward=1 has been set? The OP hasn't told us that.

Comment: @Dougie You can read it behind the link. It is set with `echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf` and the OP said he uses that tutorial.

Comment: you're assuming that the OP has followed the instructions carefully and completely.

Comment: @Dougie Yes. I see nothing wrong on what he described. What he told us is all right. He only assumed not seeing mac addresses in the arp cache is an error. Btw. routing or not routing is not the issue.

Comment: @Ingo Thank you for your quick reply to my post. You are correct that I had set routing between **uap0** and **wlan0**. I think that I have figured out what was wrong with my setup, however I am not sure why it caused this error. Previously, I had a WPA2 network w/ TKIP and CCMP (per the referenced guide) and while searching the internet for possible answers, on a _very_ old post addressed an issue with that form of auth and problems viewing neighbor clients. I opted for an unsecured hidden network, and it worked (pinging + arp)! Any idea why that may be?

Comment: @Gofex I do not see a problem at the moment. For what you described so far is not a problem. It becomes a problem if you cannot ping another client also connected to the access point of the RasPi from your Mac. This only belongs to the access point and has nothing to do with routing and internet access. Do you want internet access? Is that a problem?